# Adding image to aframe entity in React

Tags: reactjs, image-uploading, aframe

I'm trying to add an image to an Aframe entity component in React. Here's how I'm adding the image as a material on the plane geometry:

```
<Entity geometry="primitive: plane; width: 30; height: 30" 
                material={{src: "url(assets/image2.jpg)"}}
                position="0 -2 0"
                rotation="-90 0 0">
</Entity>
```

However, the image is not displaying. The image loaded properly in raw html, but isn't working with React and JSX.

I'm getting the follow errors in the console:

components:texture:warn `$s` is not a valid video +1s assets/image2.jpg

[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x7fb65d129a00]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.

Comment: Hm, the only thing I can see is that the image failed to load. Double check the path and your dev server?

Comment: How can I pass dynamic values to the src of material attribute?I tried this  material={{src:'"url('+{this.state.imageUrl}+')"'}}, but it gives error that 'this' is a reserved keyword. @ngokevin

Answer (score 1):

The right way to pass the material attribute value  can be
declare it in render() method like this

```
let material = {
            shader: 'flat',
            src : './imagepath.jpg'
        };
```

then  in your entity component pass like this

```
 <Entity  geometry={{primitive: 'sphere', radius: 5000}} material={material}  />
```

If everything is good and even then your image is not displayed, please make sure you have imported these all:-

```
import React from 'react';
import 'aframe';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import {Entity} from 'aframe-react';
```